# Using url_helpers inside lib class in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app a lib class is used to recieve emails. The email reciever class parses the email and post it to a application controller using a HTTP response. The code for this is as shown :

```
  uri = 'http://localhost:3000/incoming_mail'
  body = {'from'=> from, 'to' => to, 'subject' => subject, 'message' => message}

  response = Net::HTTP::post_form(URI.parse(uri), body)
```

The problem is I don't want to specify the complete URL. Is there any way to use 'incoming_mail_path' instead of 'localhost:3000/incoming_mail' ?
I tried to add :

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

But this is not working and gives the following error :

```
 <class:EmailReceiver>': uninitialized constant EmailReceiver::Rails (NameError)
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this.

I am posting the entire class here(Updated the class with include statement):

```
require 'mail'
require 'net/https'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'




class EmailReceiver 

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  attr_accessor :url
  def initialize
  end

  def submit(content)
    mail    = Mail.read_from_string(content)
    body    = mail.body.decoded
    from    = mail.from.first
    to      = mail.to.first
    subject = mail.subject


    if mail.multipart?
      part = mail.parts.select { |p| p.content_type =~ /text\/plain/ }.first rescue nil
      unless part.nil?
        message = part.body.decoded
      end
    else
      message = mail.decoded
    end

    unless message.nil?

      uri = incoming_mail_url
      #uri = 'http://localhost:3000/incoming_mail'
      body = {'from'=> from, 'to' => to, 'subject' => subject, 'message' => message}

      response = Net::HTTP::post_form(URI.parse(uri), body)

    end
  end


end

handler = EmailReceiver.new
handler.submit(STDIN.read)
```

Comment: try including `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` instead (not sure it will work, since there is no context)

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: i tried that also. But its giving error "`url_for': arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation (ArgumentError)". Any idea how to require routes in lib?

Comment: require 'routes' wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Debugging:

After reading your comments, i figured out that you are running it as a ruby script which does't even recognize Rails.

Before figuring out how to include all the requirements to the file. I tried to run the file through rails environment (while the server was already running) by:

```
cat sample.email | bundle exec rails runner "eval(File.read 'lib/email_receiver.rb')"
```

I got the error for the `incoming_mail_url`:

```
 Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, 
set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true (ArgumentError)
```

While the `incoming_mail_path` successfully executed `/incoming_mail` (which is not what you need).

---

#### Conclusion:

This means that what ever you do, as long as you don't run the file from the server (ex: initializers) then the host will never exist.

When you run this module from your server, its going to recogize the `route` through the `url_helpers` that you have included.

---

#### Alternative suggestion:

[Griddler](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler) gem is a Rails engine that provides an endpoint for services that convert incoming emails to HTTP POST requests. It parses these POSTs and hands off a built email object to a class implemented by you.

Comment: But the problem is with include statement. Rails showing the error :  <class:EmailReceiver>': uninitialized constant EmailReceiver::Rails (NameError) on that line. :)

Comment: This will work only if routes are found. THe class is not able to find routes. "undefined method `routes' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)". Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: @Dilnavaz I am trying to figure out the dependencies causing this issue in rails 4. Try my updated answer. Also let me know more details about how do you run it.

Comment: still getting "`<class:EmailReceiver>': undefined method `routes' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)". Are the routes really accessible inside lib in rails?

Comment: It can be tested by piping a sample email to the script using console. "cat sample.email | ruby /lib/email_receiver.rb"

Comment: @Dilnavaz I've updated the answer, I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more clarification. What do you mean by running this module from the server?

Comment: I don't have much experience in doing the such task. But let me give you a brief of what I know. First you include the `email_receiver.rb` file in your [initializers like this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/blob/master/config/initializers/griddler.rb), Then your `lib/` your file should be running. In this case griddler used a [single file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/blob/master/lib/griddler.rb) to include [all their lib files](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/tree/master/lib/griddler)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your immediate problem you may want to try to unscope your include statement. Right now it seems that interpreter thinks that  "Rails" is a class within the EmailReceiver namespace. if you Add :: to the include statement it should reference "Rails" at the top level which is what you want.

It should work, but there maybe something else wrong in your setup that is causing you to have use this otherwise unnecessary workaround

**Edit**
What I meant by add "::" just to clarify

```
include ::Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: can you suggest what may be possibly wrong in the setup?

Comment: I tried to reference rails at the top level. Only thing worked was adding a require 'rails' on the top. Is that a right way? But the only difference it makes is now the error is showing : " undefined method `routes' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)".

Comment: Where exactly is the EmailReceiver class located, what directory?also can you show the class with the include statement as it was originally?

Comment: I tried as per your comment. Still giving me "`<class:EmailReceiver>': undefined method `routes' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)". The class is located in lib folder.